# Add C Project with Makefile to Android Studio without CMakeList.txt

Tags: android, makefile, cmake, yolo

I want to add [darkenet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet) to my Android sudio project follwing this [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code).

Unfortunatly, darknet doesn't have a CMakeList.txt file but only Makefile. There is a way to add C project to Android Studio with Makefile?
If is not posible, how i can generate CMakeList.txt from Makefile? Is this a posible solution? I don't know cmake at all and I can try to write CMakeLis by myself but I can't find nothing working about this convertion.

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE: solution here https://github.com/matteomedioli/AndroidObjectDetection-OpenCV

Comment: For now I solve my problem adding OpenCVSDK in Android Studio and use method readFromDarknet